# why did blockchain .info recovery not recover all transactions?

Tags: blockchain.info, wallet-recovery

My phone was stolen. I went to recover my bitcoins that were in my Blockchain.info wallet with my pass phrase. I recover the wallet but it doesn't contain any of the transactions of the last 7 months. I was told the pass phrase would recover all my coins! What happened?

Comment: Check your address and see if the coins are there.

Comment: Yes they are there at the address I used to give out to receive them but they haven't been transferred to my new wallet in the recovery

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you used an imported address or an old address thus it can't be found by the wallet software. Only the addresses generated using the new format (bip-39) can be discovered(are deterministic). Shortly said if you used legacy addresses the wallet won't discover them because they were not derived from  a bip-39 master/wallet key.